# How to determine if something is a discrete random variable.

Tags: probability, random-variables

This seems very trivial. I am trying to determine which of these are discrete random variables on the sample space $\Omega = \{1,2,3,4\}$ with an event space defined as the power set of the sample space.

$X: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $X(\omega)$ = $-0.5\omega$

$X: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $X(\omega)$ = $-\omega$

$X: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $X(\omega)$ = $1$

$X: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $X(\omega)$ = $\sqrt\omega$

I seem to  think all of them are discrete random variables on my event space and sample space as they all take on discrete values, but me and my friend disagree...

Comment: All of them. The sample space is finite, so any random variable can have at most 4 different values.

Answer (score 0):

A discrete random variable has a countable number of possible values, which in your case is satisfied by all examples since you have a finite sample space, and hence a finite event space.